# Array Formula For Maxifs

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, max, array-formulas, google-query-language

I feel like my question should be easy to figure out, but I've looked around and can't seem to find out how to get a basic array spill function that produces the max value. Here's my simplified data set:

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 864 |
| Carrot | 189 |
| Pear | 256 |
| Apple | 975 |
| Pear | 873 |
| Carrot | 495 |
| Apple | 95 |
| Pear | 36 |
| Carrot | 804 |

My objective is to have a unique list of food (from `Col A`), that returns the max corresponding Value from `Col B`. The formula for `unique` list from `Col A` is easy... `=UNIQUE(filter(A:A,A:A<>""))`, what I'm struggling with is getting a dynamic `maxifs` to align with this.

To illustrate, if I put the unique function in cell `D2` (thus it would spill to `d4` as shown below in blue), a correct corresponding non-array function would be `=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,D2)` (shown in `column e`). I could drag this down the remaining rows but I would like this to be dynamic as there may be more food in my data set in the future.

What I would *EXPECT* to work is... `=filter(MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,D2:D),D2:D<>"")` but this returns `#Value!`. By comparison, if I were to use sumif/Average, `=filter(SUMIF(A:A,D2:D,B:B),D2:D<>"")`, I get what I WOULD expect (which really confuses me).

Is there a way to get a dynamic maxifs (or any function that produces an equal value in column E) that would spill based on unique values in column D?

[image: My data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({A:B}, "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label max(Col2)''")
```

[image]

---

bonus:

```
=QUERY({A:B}, "select Col1,max(Col2),sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label max(Col2)'',sum(Col2)''")
```

[image]

---

bonus 2:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A1:B, 2, ), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

```
2       - sort the second column of range A1:B
<empty> - or 0 or FALSE = "in descending order"
9^9     - output all rows
2       - 2nd mode of SORTN = "group by..."
1       - 1st column
1       - in ascending order
```

Comment: Thank you. The `Sortn` function is far faster. I've tried to figure out exactly what you did to achieve the result. I wasn't even expecting the fruit to appear. I understand the first sort function is resorting the starting columns by values in column b. I get lost with the next parameters (why 9^9 -- rows?)? Seems like it should be Counta(Unique(A:A))? If you wouldn't mind adding some detail to Sortn function that would be appreciated. Thanks again, I see you post a lot of answers on array formula so you'll probably get a couple more upvotes from me.

Comment: @Phil_Driscle sure. answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Responding to provide a more clear answer and simplification as others see this looking for same:

The easiest way to accomplish this is by using an array formula such as:
=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$7="Apple",$B$1:$B%7)) followed by CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER